# How to prevent component displaying before redirecting?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i'm having some trouble with my react/redux app. 
I've successfully implimented login functionality - that redirects to the home page once logged in.

The issue I have is if I go the URL, and type in /login. The login screen displays for a second, then redirects to the home page. How can I make it redirect straight away?

Note: The only way i've been able to make it work is instead of checking the state isAuthenticated, check localStorage for a token, then redirecting.

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
      store.dispatch(loadUser());
    }
  });

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div id='js-scroll'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

```
const Login = ({ login, isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Redirect to='/' />;
  }

  return ( ... )

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.authReducer.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { login }
)(Login);
```

Comment: Did you check the value of isAuthenticated and how it changes over time.  This just seems to be that it originally has a value of false, and then some process kicks in that authorizes and dispatches the change in the value.

Comment: @MonVillalon that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect hook is called after rendering is complete.  Making isAuthenticated false on the first render and after it has been commited to the dom then changed by your action.

Probably the `loadUser` function is a thunk making this intermediate state even more pronounced since there is a delay in getting the user out of the server.

If that is the case, the solution would be to convert the isAuthenticated value from a boolean flag to something with three possible values.
ex: authenticating, authenticated, unauthenticated

then you would change your route to look like this:

```
const Login = ({ login, authenticationStatus }) => {

  if(authenticationStatus === 'authenticating') {
    return null; // Or loading page
  } 

  if(authenticationStatus === 'authenticated') {
    return <Redirect to='/' />
  } 

  return ( ... )
```

Comment: ```javascript
if (isAuthenticated === null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (isAuthenticated === true) {
    return <Redirect to='/' />;
  }
  if (isAuthenticated === false) {
    return (...)
```
This works but i'm not a fan of multiple if statements, I prefer isAuthenticated to be resolved by loadUser first, before anything renders.

Comment: Using multiple if statements has nothing to do with the general approach.  Regrettably what you want of resolving an effect synchronously is not possible in the general sense.  You are going to have to wait for the request. Returning null is not ideal because you are not going to render anything that is why I suggested to use a loading component state,  this loading component can be anything maybe even a strip down version of Home with mock up data or a skeleton

Comment: Is there such thing as an automatic skeleton renderer? Like it would automatically turn the text into blocks, etc. I would hate to create a skeleton for every component.

Comment: Not fully automatic. But there are several libs that help.  A quick google search turn this up https://github.com/dvtng/react-loading-skeleton/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

What I understand is that you have a token stored in local storage and from your effect you are dispatching an action which is then loading user from that token.Once the user is loaded then you set the isAuthenticated property to true.
If thats the case then it will take some time for browser to fetch the user details thus the login screen is momentarily displayed.In this scenario then you need a loading screen while the api call for fetching user details.

What I would suggest is also keep one isLoading state apart from isAuthenticated. set isLoading  to true before making api call and once the api call is completed(success/failure) then set isLoading to false also set isAuthenticated accordingly.
In your login component check if isLoading is set to true then display loading spinner(or something else) else the regular code that you have.

Let me know if I have understood it incorrectly.

I generally have below effect for my api calls.

```
export const useHttp = (url, dependencies) => {

  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setdata] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setisLoading(false);
      setdata(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      setisLoading(false);
      console.log(err);
    })
  }, [url,  ...dependencies])

  return [isLoading, data];
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this. However I would like to know whether you can delay the render whilst the api call for fetching user details, then once recieved, render.